# clear out jquery script after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(isiPad()){
    $(document).click( function(){
        $.colorbox.close();
    });
}
```

I have a page can load colorbox's page. I have set up if user use iPad/iPhone, it can close colorbox on empty area. however when user close the box and try to reopen it, because the script already load into document so it will auto close.

Is any way to clear out `$(document).click....` after click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(document).one('click', function(){ //Just register click once
    $.colorbox.close();
});
```

**[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

Or just use `off` and `on`

```
function closeColorBox(){
    $.colorbox.close();
    $(document).off('click'); //Turn it off now.
}

 $(document).on('click', closeColorBox);
```

**[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** & **[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**